# How can I change the database (in the same server) that is used in sprigboot?

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I have a MySQL installation with an IP = X.XX.XX.XXX:PORT. If I want to connect via java, I do:

```
    jdbc:mysql://X.XX.XX.XXX:PORT/software_database
```

Where `software_store` is a database in my server, and if I want to change to another database (in the same server) in order to change I do (MySQL query):

```
    use bookstore_database;
```

then, if I want to return to the first database I do:

```
    use software_database;
```

I'm currently working with SpringBoot, but when I do the above queries doesn't make the change. Any idea of how to switch between databases on the same server without disconnect and reconnect the whole database connection?

Thanks